# What does $[\hat{A},\,\, ]$ (a commutator with one argument missing) mean?

Tags: notation, commutator

I encountered this notation on p.138 of *Condensed Matter Field Theory* (by A. Altland and B. B. Ben Simons).

It says (for $i\neq j$):

> $$ e^{-i\phi\hat{S}_i} \hat{S}_j e^{i\phi\hat{S}_i} = e^{-i\phi[\hat{S}_i,\,\,]} \hat{S}_j = \hat{S}_j\cos{\phi} + \epsilon_{ijk}\hat{S}_k\sin{\phi} $$

where it uses the fact

> $[\hat{S}_j,\,\,]^2 \hat{S}_i = \hat{S}_i $

Can some help explaining the notation $[\hat{S}_j,\,]$, and $[\hat{S}_j,\,]^2$. It's quite rare to left an argument unfilled...

BTW, $\hat{S}_i$ are generators of the Lie algebra of $\mathrm{su}(2)$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that $[A, \cdot]$ implicitly defines a function $f$ such that $f(B) \equiv [A,B]$. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operator $[A,\cdot]$ takes whatever object on which it is operating and forms the commutator. Since it is a linear operator, we can apply it as many consecutive times as we'd like. We represent the operation of applying it $n$ times as the new operator, $[A,\cdot]^n$.

For clarity, we have the following

$$
[A, \cdot] B = [A,B],
$$

$$
[A, \cdot]^2 B = [A,\cdot]([A,\cdot]B) = [A,[A,B]],
$$

$$
[A,\cdot]^3 = [A, \cdot]([A,\cdot]([A,\cdot]B)) = [A,[A,[A,B]]].
$$

and so on..

This notation allows useful formulae to be concisely expressed. An example is Hadamard’s lemma: 
$$
e^{-A}Be^{A} = e^{[A,\cdot]}B = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}[A,\cdot]^nB
$$

http://www.physicspages.com/2016/11/17/exponentials-of-operators-hadamards-lemma/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma

Hope this helps.